# container height set to css top of last child in container + a few px

Tags: jquery, html, css, containers

I am trying to set the height of a container to the last child inside the containers height from a combination of Isotope, infinite scroll and Packery. Here is what I basically have int he code.

```
   <html>
    <div id="container" class="variable-sizes isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
       <div class="isoItem isotope-item" style="position: absolute; height: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> </div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 340px; top: 0px;"></div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 680px; top: 0px;"></div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 1020px; top: 0px;"></div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 1190px; top: 0px;"></div>
       <div class="isoItem" style="position: absolute; left: 1360px; top: 2089px;"></div>
    </div>
   </html>
```

Something like this is what i am trying to achieve:

```
$('#container').css('height', $('.isoItem:last').css('top') + '317px');
```

In this case the `#container` height would be set to 2089px + 317px = 2415px
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#container').height( (parseInt( $('.isoItem:last').css('top'), 10) + 317) );
```

Why?

`$('.isoItem:last').css('top')` returns a value with units, like px, so you can't do straight math on it. Convert it to an interget first via `parseInt()`, then add your 317 (no need to append `+ 'px'` when using `.height()` as jQuery does it automatically).